# How to get items in cascade selectList after posting in ASP Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropdown, selectlist, selectlistitem

I have a cascade list for Country/Province/City and it works fine in the create and edit action except for one thing, it always becomes empty in the edit get, here is my code:

```
 public class LocationController : Controller
{
    public List<Country> countries = new List<Country>
    {
        new Country(){Id=1,Name="Country1"},
        new Country(){Id=2,Name="Country2"}
    };
    public List<Province> provinces = new List<Province>()
        {
            new Province() { Id = 1,CountryId = 1,Name = "Province1"},
            new Province() { Id = 2,CountryId = 2,Name = "Province2"},
        };
    public List<City> cities = new List<City>()
        {
            new City() { Id = 1,ProvinceId = 1,Name = "City1" },
            new City() { Id = 2,ProvinceId = 2,Name = "City2" },
            new City() { Id = 3,ProvinceId = 2,Name = "City3" },
        };

    public IActionResult Province(int value)
    {
        var l = provinces.Where(x => x.CountryId == value).ToList();
        return Json(l);
    }

    public IActionResult City(int value)
    {
        var c = cities.Where(c => c.ProvinceId == value).ToList();
        return Json(c);
    }
}
```

the Edit view:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label asp-for="Country" class="col-form-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select id="CountryList" asp-for="Country" asp-items="@new LocationController().countries.Select(c=> new SelectListItem() {Text=c.Name,Value=c.Id.ToString() }).ToList() as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>" class="form-control">
                        <option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label asp-for="Province" class="col-form-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select id="ProvinceList" asp-for="Province" data-url="@Url.Action("Province","Location")" class="form-control">
                        <option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label asp-for="City" class="col-form-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select id="CityList" asp-for="City" data-url="@Url.Action("City","Location")" class="form-control">
                        <option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#CountryList").change(function () {
                $("#CityList").empty();
                var v = $(this).val();
                var url = $("#ProvinceList").data("url") + '?value=' + v;
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    $("#ProvinceList").empty();
                    $("#ProvinceList").append('<option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $("#ProvinceList")
                            .append($("<option>").text(item.name).val(item.id));
                    });
                });
            });
            $("#ProvinceList").change(function () {
                var v = $(this).val();
                var url = $("#CityList").data("url") + '?value=' + v;
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    $("#CityList").empty();
                    $("#CityList").append('<option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $("#CityList")
                            .append($("<option>").text(item.name).val(item.id));
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        $('#formId').submit(function () {
            $('#CountryList option').val(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            });
            $('#ProvinceList option').val(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            });
            $('#CityList option').val(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

and of course in the get action I tried to get the user's location from the database, and its working in the get:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        EditUserViewModel modelVM = new EditUserViewModel
        {
            Country = user.Country,
            Region = user.Region,
            City = user.City,
        };
        return View(modelVM);
    }
```

[image: Get edit action]

but in the view the province/region and city are empty:

[image: Edit view]

If I click update province and city will be null.

Comment: What is your get action?Did you mean when you post the select item to the edit get action,the data is always be null?

Comment: @Rena no there are data, but not in the view. Sorry for not being clear I added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo about how to pass the selected item to the action:

Model:

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Province
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

It seems you want to edit one user and the edit view would display the user's default city,province and country.So I think your js is no need in edit view.

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
}
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public  string Province { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml(display the user data):

```
@model IEnumerable<UserProfile>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Province)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Province)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a>               
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit.cshtml:

```
@model EditUserViewModel
<form id="formId" asp-controller="Location" asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label asp-for="Country" class="col-form-label"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">

            //change here....
            <select id="CountryList" asp-for="Country" asp-items="@ViewBag.Country" class="form-control">
                <option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label asp-for="Province" class="col-form-label"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">

            //change here....
            <select id="ProvinceList" asp-for="Province" asp-items="@ViewBag.Province" data-url="@Url.Action("Province","Location")" class="form-control">
                <option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label asp-for="City" class="col-form-label"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">

            //change here....
            <select id="CityList" asp-for="City" asp-items="@ViewBag.City" data-url="@Url.Action("City","Location")"  class="form-control">
                <option selected disabled value="">--- Choose ---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="aaa" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#CountryList").change(function () {
                $("#CityList").empty();
                var v = $(this).val();
                var url = $("#ProvinceList").data("url") + '?value=' + v;
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    $("#ProvinceList").empty();
                    $("#ProvinceList").append('<option selected disabled value="">--- اختر ---</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $("#ProvinceList")
                            .append($("<option>").text(item.name).val(item.id));
                    });
                });
            });
            $("#ProvinceList").change(function () {
                var v = $(this).val();
                var url = $("#CityList").data("url") + '?value=' + v;
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    $("#CityList").empty();
                    $("#CityList").append('<option selected disabled value="">--- اختر ---</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $("#CityList")
                            .append($("<option>").text(item.name).val(item.id));
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        $('#formId').submit(function () {
            $('#CountryList option').val(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            });
            $('#ProvinceList option').val(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            });
            $('#CityList option').val(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{      
    private List<UserProfile> users = new List<UserProfile>()
    {
        new UserProfile(){Id="1",Province="1",Country="1",City="1"},
        new UserProfile(){Id="2",Province="2",Country="2",City="3"},
    };    
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(users);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
    {
        var user = users.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();          
        ViewBag.Province = new SelectList(new LocationController().provinces,"Id","Name", user.Province);
        ViewBag.City = new SelectList(new LocationController().cities,"Id","Name", user.City);
        ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(new LocationController().countries,"Id","Name", user.Country);
        EditUserViewModel modelVM = new EditUserViewModel
        {
            Country = user.Country,
            Province = user.Province,
            City = user.City,
        };
        return View(modelVM);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(string city, string province, string country)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! this works perfectly, I really appreciate your help!